# Addition of readonly / disable paremtru depending on the class tr / td in html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a question, can it be set to add the `ReadOnly` / `Disable` parameter to `DropDownlistFor` in the specified class `<'tr class = "TR_two">'` or `<'td class = "TD_two">'`

In `<'tr class = "TR_one">' or <'td class = "TD_one">'` would remain unchanged.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="TR_one">
            <td class="TD_one">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Urlopy))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="TR_two">
            <td class="TD_two">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Urlopy))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist" })</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of jQuery to achieve this.
Add below line inside your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" />
```

Then, add below script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("td.TD_one").find(".selectboxlist").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    });  
</script>
```

Above script selects **td** element with 'class = TD_one'. Then finds its child element that has 'class = selectboxlist' and sets its 'disabled' property.